Event study with regional variations
I’m new to financial econometrics and would appreciate any guidance. I’m working on an event study to examine abnormal stock returns in response to political events in the U.S. Since these events might affect returns in some states but not others, should I run an aggregate event study/regression with state fixed effects, or would it be better to conduct the study separately for each state? Thank you!

If you think some of the parameters are common across states, state fixed effects may be the better option. If you do not think there are any common parameters across states, separate analysis for each state probably makes more sense.

You may have better luck on the Economics stack exchange
